# find all the units of $R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}] = \{ a + b\sqrt{-n} \mid a,b \in \mathbb Z\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $n$ be a natural number. Define the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}] = \{ a + b\sqrt{-n} \mid a,b \in \mathbb Z\}$. Find all the units in $R$.

There is a hint that we can define $H: R \to \mathbb{Z}$ by $H(a + b\sqrt{-n}) = a^2 + nb^2$. I could show that for any $c,d \in R$ we have $N(cd) = N(c) \cdot N(d)$. I don't know how the hint could help but I think we can go straight to find the units without the hint. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $x$ is a unit, then there is $y$ in $R$ such that $xy=1$. What does this say on the level of norms?